# Livecycle - Convert PDF (XFA) to HTML

Tags: html, pdf, adobe, livecycle, xfa

I have created a few PDF (XFA) forms using the Adobe Livecycle ES4 Forms Designer.
I want to convert those forms into HTML and after reading a few posts, Livecycle server gives that option.

But I could not find a way to install the Livecycle server.

Has anyone rendered the livecycle PDF forms to HTML? If yes, how?